# is it a good practice to create an SKSpriteNode within a subclassed SKSpriteNode?

Tags: swift, subclass, skspritenode

This code here subclasses SKSpriteNode and initializes it that accepts SKScene

```
import SpriteKit

class Spaceship: SKSpriteNode{

var spaceship:SKTexture
var hitpoint = 100
var thescene:SKScene

var lazer5:SKSpriteNode?
var lazer5_pathofdestruction:SKSpriteNode?

init(skScene:SKScene) {

    thescene = skScene
    self.spaceship  = SKTexture(imageNamed:"Spaceship")
    super.init(texture: spaceship, color: SKColor.clearColor(), size: spaceship.size())
    self.name = "Spaceship"
    self.setScale(0.10)
    self.position =  CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(skScene.frame), CGRectGetMidY(skScene.frame))

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
.......
```

This Class (Spaceship) has a method that will fire the dualcanon:

```
 func firedualcanon() {

    let canonposition = [10.00 , -10.00]
    let fireSound = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("dualcanon.wav", waitForCompletion: false)
    let targeting = SKAction.sequence([


        SKAction.runBlock{

            for position in canonposition {

                let canon = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.whiteColor(), size: CGSize(width:4, height: 3))
                canon.name = "weapon"
                canon.position = CGPointMake(self.position.x - CGFloat(position), self.position.y)
                let projectile = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: self.position.x - CGFloat(position), y: self.thescene.frame.height + 200 ),duration: 1.50)

                GlobalReference.setPhysicsBody(canon,collidertype: GlobalVariable.ColliderType.Light)

                self.thescene.addChild(canon)
                let bulletaction = SKAction.sequence([projectile,SKAction.removeFromParent()])
                canon.runAction(bulletaction)

            }


        }


        , SKAction.waitForDuration(0.10)

        ])

    self.thescene.runAction(
        SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.group([fireSound,targeting])),
        withKey: "fireweapons")



}
```

as you can see in the initialization I used the SKTexture but now in the method firedualcanon() I created a canon using SKSpriteNode.

Is this a good Swift Programming practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When coding sprite-based games, **it is quite common practice** to have your game objects be subclasses of the sprite class (or more generic nodes), even before Swift and SpriteKit (e.g., Cocos2d/Objective-C).

Some purist might argue that you should decouple the *model* (data), *views* (sprites) and *controllers* (game logic) into separate objects, but in simple games that can lead to having a huge number of classes, each of which does very little.

(*In my opinion*, it is really about preference and what is convenient for your particular app)

If you still wish to go in that direction, you could have each object's logic/state represented by a non-SpriteKit class (e.g., Swift root class or subclass of `NSObject`), with each object somehow linked to the sprite that represents it on screen (a reference, unique id, etc.), the details up to you.

Then, on each frame, update the visual state (position, etc.) of each sprite based on the logical (game) state of the model object (e.g., "spaceship") they represent.

Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with NicolasMiari. It depends on your particular game but it's usual to have a SKNode class that consist on one, two or more SKSpriteKitNode in order to represent it properly. For example, what if your spaceship can have a little spaceship as a satellite with its particular actions, animations, collisions etc? In cases like that is easier to have it a as separate sprite.